# Incorrect Breakpoints Triggered with Property getters when Debugging Windows Store App with Release Configuration

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

I'm noticing some odd behaviour when I'm debugging an app written in C++/CX in Release configuration.  FYI in case it's relevant  I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Community (Update 4).

When I place a breakpoint on a some property getter such as Type1::Label::get() I'm noticing it seems to break when Type2::Label::get() would be invoked but breaks as if the Type1 method was invoked.  I'm concerned that there may be something wrong that is causing this problem but I'm perplexed as to why this would only be apparent in Release configuration.

The app appears to otherwise function correctly. Is there a known issue that might explain this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably correct behaviour caused by code optimizations.

If the compiled code for the two get methods is the same then the optimizer will often point both functions at the same location rather than duplicating the code in the final assembly.

Release builds are almost always optimized. Debug builds are almost never optimized.

Optimization makes release builds faster and smaller than debug builds but also much more difficult to debug.